# How to pass props to React child components whose required types we don't know yet

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to pass props down to children components whose required types we don't yet know? Something like this:

```
interface CardProps<T> {
  set: SetProps<T>;
  setSet: Dispatch<SetStateAction<SetProps<T>>>;
  children: ReactNode;
}

const RenderCards = <T extends object>({ set, setSet, children }: CardProps<T>) => (
  <>
    {set &&
      set.data &&
      set.data.map((item: T, idx: number) => (
        <SwipeBox
          key={idx}
          state={{ set, setSet }}
        >
          <MovieCard movie={item as MovieType} /> // This is too specific, want to delete.
          {children ...props} // This is flexible, but wrong.
        </SwipeBox>
      ))}
  </>
);
```

So far, I've come up with Context API as a viable solution. It's certainly less boilerplate than Redux but, is there an even easier way?

Comment: If you want to use ``typescript``, you should use it the correct way. Is your problem that ``set.data`` contains objects of different types? If so, two possible answers. The short one, use ``<MovieCard movie={item as any} />``. The better alternative, use type union to define beforehand all the different types of ``set.data``'s objects. Without more context that's the best I can advise

Comment: @KibongeMurphy yes, the data will be of different types, but in this case it's not possible to know what's coming in and how it will be used, so i can't really define them yet. `item as any` is a really good compromise though. thanks!

Comment: There's a few ways to do this.  You can use `React.cloneElement` to inject values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464194/how-to-define-typescript-for-react-children-map **but** if the injected values are required props then you'll get errors on the JSX when you write them without those props.  You can make `children` be a function which takes your props and renders them.  You can also use a prop called `Render` or `CardBody` to pass a component and then call the component with your props.  In the current setup, is `children` always a single node or do you need to support arrays?

Comment: Also what are the props that you are passing? `props` is not defined here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit about your intentions, but I am interpreting this as:

- You want to support rendering different kinds of cards for different `T` types.
- You want to pass through certain props to every individual card.

I came up with a solution based on a render props pattern.  We now have two generics -- `T` which is still the item type and `Extra` which is the props that we pass through.

Each individual card will receive the properties of the item as props, all of the `Extra` props, and `set` and `setSet` (not sure if those last two are actually needed).

The card group requires `set`, `setSet`, the `Extra` props, and a `Render` component for the individual card.

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, ComponentType, useState } from "react";

interface SetProps<T> {
  data: T[];
}

interface CardProps<T> {
  set: SetProps<T>;
  setSet: Dispatch<SetStateAction<SetProps<T>>>;
}

type CardGroupProps<T, Extra = {}> = Extra &
  CardProps<T> & {
    Render: ComponentType<T & Extra & CardProps<T>>;
  };

const CardGroup = <T extends object, Extra extends object>(
   {set, setSet, Render, ...extra}: CardGroupProps<T, Extra>
) => (
  <>
    {set.data.map((item: T, idx: number) => (
      <SwipeBox 
        key={idx} 
        state={{ set, setSet }}
      >
        <Render 
           set={set} 
           setSet={setSet} 
           {...(extra as Extra)} 
           {...item} 
        />
      </SwipeBox>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Here's a silly example to show usage.  Here our `RenderMovieCard` component requires the `Movie` item and also a `color` prop.  You will get an error if you try to call a `CardGroup` with `Render={RenderMovieCard}` without passing this required `color` prop.

```
interface Movie {
  title: string;
}

const RenderMovieCard = ({ title, color }: Movie & { color: string }) => (
  <div style={{ color }}>{title}</div>
);

export default () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<SetProps<Movie>>({
    data: [{ title: "Jaws" }, { title: "Star Wars" }]
  });

  return (
    <CardGroup
      set={movies}
      setSet={setMovies}
      Render={RenderMovieCard}
      color="red"
    />
  );
};
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-65998205-e37xd)

Comment: Took me some time to grok and wow. So cool. Thanks!